# Changing the size of arrow boxes of the sunburst visualization

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I am using Kerry Rodden's fork open source d3 and html script for sunburst visualization.

https://github.com/mojoaxel/d3-sunburst

It works on my data but I have longer labels so it is overlapping in the legend arrows on top left.

I am not coming from html/css background so not able to figure out which element in the code needs to be changed to get the right alignment.

This is how it looks currently:

[image]

If you see top left has text overlapping the boxes. I want to elongate the box or reduce the text font size.

Also possible to increase the size of main sunburst chart on browser? Like possible to make it bigger?

Here is the css file for this code.

```
#sunburst-breadcrumbs {
  width: 600px;
  height: 70px;
}

#sunburst-legend {
  padding: 10px 0 0 3px;
}

#sunburst-breadcrumbs text,
#sunburst-legend text {
  font-weight: 600;
  fill: #fff;
}

#sunburst-chart {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -375px;
}

#sunburst-chart path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

#sunburst-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -1.25em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
}
```

I think these alignment issues might be fixed in this css parameters. But after playing with few don't see the soln yet.

Thanks

Edit 2:

The middle text sentence is missing and the rectangles curtail to only 4 even when the path is more.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this version of a sunburst,

you can increase the width of the rectangle here (in sunburst.js):

```
    // Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
    breadcrumbs: {
        w: 75,
        h: 30,
        s: 3,
        t: 10
    },
```

To decrease font-size, add the following css section:

```
  ...
  #sunburst-breadcrumbs text{
    font-size: 3px;
  }
```

In the original sunburst visualization from [Kerry Roddan](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/766f8f6d31f645c39f488a0befa1e3c8), you can increase the width of the rectangle here:

```
// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 175, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};
```

To decrease font-size, add the following css section:

```
<style>
  #sequence text{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Increasing width of polygon and decreasing font-size: https://bl.ocks.org/ee2dev/4153ee8eafb5a27d32588b12877a0ea7

Comment: So both width and font are new sections I need to add to the above code? Its not part of same sections?Like he has #sunburst-breadcrumbs section. I tried changing those but it didn't change. Like is it the same as padding above?

Comment: No, both options refer to different code sections. If you want to decrease the font-size, just add the ```<style>...</style> section of my answer in the *index.html* file at the very bottom of the ```<head> element - as I did it in the answer link at the bottom

Comment: For increasing the polygon (the arrows on the top left) you go to the sixth line of the file sequences.js

Comment: I think ur code above is from sunburst.js and not sunburst.css which I pasted. I do see those two section infact a section in js script of height and width of sunburst chart too

Comment: if you want to adjust the CSS file you have, you should just add the ```#sequence text { font-size: 10px;} to the bottom of the file. That changes the font-size within the arrows.

Comment: hold on. I am not using original Kerry Roden's code. Just checked. I am using the code from this forked github

https://github.com/mojoaxel/d3-sunburst. So the .js file is a bit different than Kerry Rodden

Comment: then look at line 31 in sunburst.js, there you can specify the width of the breadcrumbs (thats what the author calles there aorrows in the upper left)

Comment: Yeah I checked. It works. Also line above that has width and height for the whole chart one can play with. Just that text font is giving issues. It still goes beyond for some cases

Comment: font is not reducing. I went all the way to 3px and added that line in css file at the bottom.

Comment: yes, my answer was based on the source from kerry roddan which I refered, too. Please update your question to refer to your mojoaxel version so people have a chance understanding what you want. To reduce the font-size there add the following to the css file: ```#sunburst-breadcrumbs text{
  font-size: 10px;}```

Comment: u want to add #sunburst-breadcrumbs text{ font-size: 10px; } OR 

#sequence text { font-size: 10px;}?

Comment: The first one for your code from  github.com/mojoaxel/d3-sunburst. The latter one, if you use the original code from Roddan.

Comment: Well used the first one. It still doesn't lower the font size. Still same I get. I got it to 8px

Comment: Let's stop with the comments, no one wants to read 100 comments. Please update your question to 1) correctly refer to the source code you used and 2) add the .css file with the new selector. For me, it works fine on the github.com/mojoaxel/d3-sunburst code.

Comment: updated. Ok I see it works now. But somehow the text color went black from white. And I want white as the boxes are dark color.

Comment: got it white back. Just that the right end numbers get hidden. But rest things work fine

Comment: ok, I also updated my answer accordingly. if it works, please accept my answer. if you have new questions, please open a new question

Comment: There is one issue I am seeing. When I have elongated the boxes (width) now it is only showing 4 boxes. If I further elongate the box it shows only three arrow boxes even when the path is more in the main chart. This is an issue I am seeing with increasing width of boxes. It is not showing boxes for other paths and curtails it to 4

Comment: I am also not seeing the middle text sentence in the center of the main chart being displayed

Comment: pls check edit 2 I added the screenshot. Middle text sentence is missing and the rectangles are curtailed to only 4 instead of whole sequence

Comment: added another question for this new issue. Pls check.  @ee2dev

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818034/changing-the-rectangle-size-causes-to-curtail-the-path-in-sunburst-visualization